# ngIf with multiple condition using OR operator not working

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

```html
 <ng-container *ngIf="(element.documentStatus === 'DELETED' || element.documentStatus === 
      'SUPERSEDED' || element.documentStatus === 'UNDER_QC_REVIEW')">
          Hide
 </ng-container>
 <ng-container *ngIf="(element.documentStatus !== 'DELETED' || element.documentStatus !== 
    'SUPERSEDED' || element.documentStatus !== 'UNDER_QC_REVIEW')">
          Show
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: Please explain what behavior you expect and what behavior you are observing.

Comment: When negating a logic expression, `or` becomes `and`. So if `a == b || a == c` negated is `a != b && a != c`

Answer (score 1):

instead of doing two if statements, you should use if/else.
See example:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="element.documentStatus === 'DELETED' || element.documentStatus === 'SUPERSEDED' || element.documentStatus === 'UNDER_QC_REVIEW'; else myElseBlock">
    Hide
</ng-container>
<ng-template #myElseBlock>Show</ng-template>
```